# Refresh child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem to solve this case.

how to refresh child component 1, when the data changes in child component 2. Child 1 and Child 2 are in the same parent.

[image]

Real cases I have:

[image]

In this case, if there is an addition to the PO item, then I want the payment component to also refresh to get the results from the API. How does it do it?

And in the implementation, I want the payment data to also be refreshed (like calling the API) when I add items:

[image]

Sorry if my English is not good.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to do but if you want them both to be aware of the same state you could wrap them in a Provider from a Context and then hook into the context from both child components? then you can have them share the same data and set up some side effects. although not sure that's the best use of useEffect but it would probably work

Comment: Yes, that's right.. I want, when I add product items and their prices - item component , I want to call up the details of the payment (payment component). I'm starting to understand, I might be able to combine useEffect with context. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you’re trying to solve is a very common problem in React. And it’s solved very simply by “lifting state up”

[The official react docs on it are here](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components)

> Sharing State Between Components
> Sometimes, you want the state of two components to always change together. To do it, remove state from both of them, move it to their closest common parent, and then pass it down to them via props. This is known as lifting state up, and it’s one of the most common things you will do writing React code.

It’s the recommended way (obviously, as it’s in the official docs) to share data between components. It keeps things simple, maintainable and, most importantly, readable.

There are no performance or best practice concerns, don’t be swayed by people using words like “prop drilling”, it’s the recommended pattern.

My own personal opinion on context is that it often (not always) makes things more complicated by moving the logic of the state behaviour further away from the components that are involved making it more difficult to reason about. Context is not bad at all, but it’s perhaps overused to its detriment, and it’s not likely you need it here

Comment: this seems simpler. from the documentation you linked, I only need one state in the parent as a trigger point (activedIndex). If the panel is opened, it will trigger this panel index. And of course panels with other indexes will be closed. If I apply the three components Purchasing (root), Items (Child 1 - index 1), Payment (Child 2 - index 2), I will send seActivateIndex(1) to Payment to trigger changes to Items. Oh my God... Thank you. This is very, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. The common/standard way to achieve this is by using state management library like `Redux` or `React Context` which will allow you to share states among different components by wrapping it inside a `Provider` More on that [here](https://redux.js.org/). However in case of only one level such as in your problem you can use solution 2 below.
2. In case of one level (in your problem) you can simply use a concept called `prop passing/lifting state up` You can keep the state of `Child Component 2` that you want to trigger the change in `Child Component 1` in the `Parent Component` and pass the state down from the `Parent Component` to both the `Child Component 1` and `Child Component 2` and now whenever that state which is now in `Parent Component` changes it will re-render the child components. More on that [here](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components)

*Keep in mind that passing props through **multiple child components** is not recommended to avoid [prop drilling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-prop-drilling-and-how-to-avoid-it/)*

Comment: I agree with your answer in number 1. It makes more sense than number 2. Number 2 makes components difficult to maintain. Thank you for your answer, this is very helpful. I will use context from react. Thank You...

Comment: Number 2 is actually the more common  and maintainable way to do this. Even suggested by react docs. It’s one of the central themes of react and it’s called “lifting state up”. The comment about “prop drilling” has nothing to do with anything

Comment: @AdamJenkins I have updated my answer to make it more clear to OP. I agree that "lifting state up" is better way of doing this specifically in this case, but in case of multiple children it becomes increasingly difficult to manage hence the concept of "prop drilling". I know that in this case there is only one level of "prop passing" this is why I gave both approaches to OP and also mentioned when not to use this approach.

Comment: Redux is over the top in a lot of instances; it's not as needed as it used to be with the advancements React has made over the past few versions. Redux is still totally valid but in a lot of cases its overkill when you can just use contexts etc...